# how to include python modules not under distribution root in setup.py?

Tags: python, distribution

I am new to python and am figuring out and using distutils to create a distribution for a python project,

in the `setup.py` file you indicate which python modules to be included 
with the option

`py_modules = ['mod1', 'pkg.mod2']`

which would include the files under the distribution root `'mod1'` and also can include files in packages within the distribution root `'pkg/mod2'`.  Is it possible to include files above the distribution root folder?
for example a python module found several directories above:`../../../../../pkg2/mod3`

or must I go about changing the distribution root?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use package_dir for this.

```
setup(
    package_dir={'mod3': '../../../../../pkg2/mod3'},
    packages=['mod3']
)
```